# Magento: product with custom options, needs ajax update with price and sku

Tags: ajax, magento, product

I want to show the SKU of a customizable article. Have a look at the screenshot below.

If I select color, length and so, the price will be updated via ajax. So far, very good. But I want to display the SKU of the article too.

The site calls this url via ajax:

```
http://SERVER/oi/ajax/co/?id=5106&pid=5114
```

and returns me the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    window.opConfig = new Product.Options([]);
    $('product_addtocart_form').encoding = 'multipart/form-data';
    //]]>
</script>
```

which file should I update / alter for this change ?? Where the correct js for this new Product.Options ??

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it... well. After taking a break I've came up with the following solution:

I've put this code in the view.pthtml of the product (the html which displays the product actually)

```
<div style="text-align:left; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;">
<div id="pv_article_sup_art_no" style="display:none;text-align:right;"></div>
</div>
```

Then I added the following code to the scpajaxoptions.phtml

```
<?php 
$data = $this->getProduct()->toArray();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#pv_article_sup_art_no').html("Artikelnummer: <?php echo $data['a_sup_artno']; ?>");
    jQuery('#pv_article_sup_art_no').show();
</script>
```

eh voila.... it works !